# Do i need to stop my localhost server when pushing, pulling or merging code to/from github repository?

Tags: reactjs, git

I have two terminals open in VS Code for React development. One for running the server and one for running bash commands. Now i've been told this is a bad practise as it creates problems in the build of the project. If you want to commit, pull, push, merge you should stop the server and perform these actions and then restart server. Stopping/Restarting the server takes time and seems like a hassle to me. If anyone could answer that thanks

Answer (score 0):

Largely speaking, this should be fine. Assuming you are using some kind of development server (which is monitoring files for changes), any changes that are applied because of a git pull/merge/etc will cause your app to reload (usually in some optimised way).

AN exception to this can be if files that configure the development server change, as it has probably read its configuration on start and thus those changes might not take effect.

Another exception is adding/changing dependencies. If some new/different packages were added to your package.json, then you'd need to rerun `npm install` again before starting the development server again.

Pushing code to git while the server is running is not problematic either.

So in summary, it's usually fine to do this and is not destructive in any way. If something unpredictable happens, try restarting the dev server (and possible rerunning `npm install`).